# Is there any alternative to `for await ... of` for Deno.listen()

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, deno

I am new to Deno. In my first step to build Deno simple HTTP server, I saw this on the documentation, It works pretty well:

```js
const server = Deno.listen({ port: 80 })

for await (const conn of server) {
  /* etc... */
}
```

Why Deno documentation prefer `for await of` syntax to listen such connections.

Is there any alternative to this? Is this the only way to handle `Deno.Conn` from `Deno.listen()`? Or just a preferred way?

Comment: "for await" is for calling an async iterator, so instead of locking up your code waiting for the next item in the iterator to arrive it releases it to perform another task and then resumes once the next item has arrived why is that not desired behaviour?

Comment: @MikeT Node. js uses `server.on()` or something similar to that to handle Asynchrnous events. And yeah, I love this syntax too however, I am just curious why Deno uses for await instead of event-based syntax.

Comment: @thebluetropics Deno uses event callbacks when the web does, but one of its core philosophical tenets is [promises over callbacks](https://deno.land/manual@v1.24.0/introduction#comparison-to-nodejs): "All async actions in Deno return a promise. Thus Deno provides different APIs than Node."

Comment: the `for await` is a relatively new addition to js as is `async iteration` so deno is just exploiting a new feature that wasn't around when node was developed, and as the saying goes if it aint broke don't fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a pattern, and you're going to see it more in future TypeScript/JavaScript because it is more concise (in most cases). (See end of answer for more.)

This is explained in [HTTP Server APIs (low level) | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.24.0/runtime/http_server_apis_low_level#handling-connections):

> There is also the `.accept()` method on the listener which can be used:
>
> ```ts
> const server = Deno.listen({ port: 8080 });
>
> while (true) {
>   try {
>     const conn = await server.accept();
>     // ... handle the connection ...
>   } catch (err) {
>     // The listener has closed
>     break;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Whether using the async iterator or the `.accept()` method, exceptions can be thrown and robust production code should handle these using `try ... catch` blocks. Especially when it comes to accepting TLS connections, there can be many conditions, like invalid or unknown certificates which can be surfaced on the listener and might need handling in the user code.
>
> ...

And — although it's not directly documented in the manual — you can, of course, also use the standard `asyncIterator`:

```ts
const server = Deno.listen({ port: 80 });

const iter = server[Symbol.asyncIterator]();

while (true) {
  try {
    const { done, value: conn } = await iter.next();
    if (done) break;
    conn;
    //^? const conn: Deno.Conn

    // ... handle the connection ...
  } catch (ex) {
    // The listener has closed
    break;
  }
}
```

---

Regarding [`for await...of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of): consider the more concise syntax introduced with the `for...of` loop compared to the classic `for` loop when iterating an array:

```js
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

// for loop
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  console.log(item);
}

// for...of loop
for (const item of arr) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Just like it gave us the opportunity for more concise syntax, so does `for await...of`.

Comment: looks like using the `asyncIteator` way is what happens behind the Deno implementation of `Deno.listen()`