# How can you use the Deno.watchFs infinite async iterable without blocking?

Tags: javascript, async-await, filesystemwatcher, deno, async-iterator

So [Deno](https://deno.land/) has a [filesystem watcher API](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.watchFs) that seems... obtuse to me. Perhaps that's simply due to my ignorance of async iterators. It's shown to be used like so:

```
const watcher = Deno.watchFs("/directory")
for await (const event of watcher) {
    //process events
}
//code here is never executed
```

`watcher` is an async iterable which is infinite, which means this for loop will block forever. What is a sensible way to write code to process these events such that it will not block the function?

*Aside: why on earth did they not simply have a callback / event listener style interface?*

Comment: Well it blocks *only that function*, nothing else. Don't use it with top-level `await`.

Comment: Btw I'm reasonably certain that the iterator will end once you call `watcher.close()`, also you can always `break` from the loop.

Comment: For your aside, see [Is there any alternative to `for await ... of` for Deno.listen()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73077697/1048572) or just use `AsyncIterator.from(watcher).forEach(eventHandler);` from the [iterator helpers proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have anything after the loop, other than code you want to run after the `FsWatcher` is closed.

```
async function watchFs(){
  const watcher = Deno.watchFs("/directory")
  for await (const event of watcher) {
      //process events
  }
  // some finalisation
}

const watcher = watchFs().catch(handleSomething)
moreThings()
```

It's a different way of displaying the same concept. I wouldn't argue that `async`/`await` "is a bad design" when it's doing what was intended of showing you the flow of an asynchronous program in a sequential view.

```
async function watchFs(){
  const stream = stream.watchFs("/directory")

  stream.on('change', (event) => {
     // process events
  })

  stream.on('end', () => {
     // some finalisation
  }

  stream.on('error', (error) => {
      handleSomething()
  })
 
  return stream 
}

const watcher = watchFs()
```

Comment: Saying "it's simple, just don't have any code after the for-loop" is a bit like going to the doctor and telling them it hurts when you raise your arm only for them to tell you "well then don't raise your arm." I guess I solved this by utilizing an immediately invoked async arrow function. It works but it seems like the use of an infinite async iterator is a bad design if it makes this sort of thing necessary.

Comment: It's a different way of displaying the same concept, there is something in the background for ever with this filewatcher no matter which way it's called.  I wouldn't argue that `async`/`await` "is a bad design" when it's doing what was intended of showing you the flow of an asynchronous program in a sequential view.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing it. Would you then advocate that we replace `document.addEventListener` in browser code with an async iterators so we instead write code like `for await (const event of element.clickWatcher) {}`? How is that better?

Comment: @Chris_F You can e.g. easily stop the subscription by `break`ing from the loop, no need to use complicated `removeEventListener` syntax. Also, if done properly, error handling from the event handling code becomes much more straightforward. And when taken to the extreme, [this style of coding can make it easier to reason about asynchronous sequential execution](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/).

Comment: @Chris_F I agree that the simple case is not as simple but as Bergi mentioned, as soon as you add to the simple case, async/await really help with the error handling and sequencing of those tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run any [`for await...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) asynchronously in the same scope as your other code without `await`ing its completion, you'll have to wrap it in another async function and call that function without the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword.

You can create that kind of abstraction without much code:

```ts
async function forEachAsync<T>(
  asyncIterable: AsyncIterable<T>,
  callback: (result: T) => void,
) {
  for await (const result of asyncIterable) callback(result);
}

const watcher = Deno.watchFs(Deno.cwd());

forEachAsync(watcher, (fsEvent) => {
  const { kind, ...rest } = fsEvent;
  console.log(kind, rest);
}).catch((reason) => {/* handle */});

console.log("Watching in progress");

// Close it whenever you want (e.g. after 2s):
setTimeout(() => {
  watcher.close();
  console.log("Finished watching");
}, 2e3);
```